# Prevent default behaviour of ringtonepreference in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

When i click on ringtonePreference it open a dialog with list of ringtones.But  I want to open my custom dialog when click on preference instead of default dialog. Anyone help me with code sample.

My preference xml for ringtonePreference  -

```
<RingtonePreference
            android:key="@string/pref_key_sound_for_call"
            android:title="@string/text_title_sound_for_call"
            android:summary="@string/text_summery_sound_for_call" />
```

And SettingsFragment for opening my custom dialog   -

```
preferenceForCustomSoudCall.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                showInAppPurchaseDialog();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I want to open my custom dialog when click on preference instead of default dialog

Then do not use a `RingtonePreference`. Use a `Preference`, and register your click handler as you have in the question. Or, create a custom `DialogPreference`, rather than displaying the entire dialog yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Is there any way for  CheckboxPreference and EditTextPreference too without using preference?

Comment: @AGMTazim: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question.

Comment: My question is - Is there any way to change default behavior of CheckboxPreference and EditTextPreference without using preference? I mean to open custom dialog instead of default.

Comment: @AGMTazim: If you do not want the standard behavior of a specific preference type (e.g., `CheckBoxPreference`), do not use that specific preference type. Create your own preference class that implements what you want.